# Is $e^{\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]}$ equal to $\mathbb{E}\left[e^X\right]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, expected-value

Could anyone please tell me if $e^{\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]}$ is equal to $\mathbb{E}\left[e^X\right]$?

I have:

$\prod^n_{i=1} e^{\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]}$

and I'm wondering if I can rearrange this to:

$\prod^n_{i=1} e^{\mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]} = \prod^n_{i=1} \mathbb{E}\left[e^{X_i}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\prod^n_{i=1} e^{X_i}\right]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, expectation is a linear operator but it does not have such a property as that. We can do: Jensen's inequality says if f is convex, then $f(E(X))\le E(f(X))$. In fact because $e^x$ is convex, we have:

$$ e^{E(X)}\le E(e^X)$$

Thus

$$\prod e^{E(X)}\le \prod E(e^X)$$

Comment: Ah, thank you! Thanks for pointing out and explaining Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. But from Jensen's inequality, due to convexity of $e^x$,
$$\mathbb{E}[e^X] \ge e^{\mathbb{E}[X]}$$.

Verify with $X$ distributed as bernoulli $p$ example. Equality above will happen when $X$ is deterministic.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your answer is just as helpful as Stacker's. I only marked theirs as the accepted answer instead of yours because of the extra explanation of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: No worries. The earlier answer popped up a short while before I could complete mine. And I do agree that the other answer is better :)